# How can we declare a gcp cloud armor advance mode rule options block in terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud, google-cloud-armor

How can we  declare a gcp cloud armor advance mode rule options block in terraform

we are trying to setup the cloud armor security  for Load balancer VIA terraform but not sure how to declare the advance mode rule in terraform ( for validating the https request headers in the defined rule ).

trying to validate the http request header for advance rule

Comment: What is **advance rule**? Do you mean **advanced match condition**? What is the rule that you created? Edit your question with details including the Terraform that you have written. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I got a perfect solution ( well-tested ) which can help you.

First thing, adaptive_protection_config block in the "google_compute_security_policy" security policy is not GA.

If you would like to avail this feature, you need to go with the provider "google-beta" which can also be mentioned in the resource level.

Here is how you can enroll the policy with "Adaptive Protection Mode"

```
resource "google_compute_security_policy" "policy" {
     name = "my-policy"
     description = "Cloud Armor Security Policy"
     provider    = "google-beta"
     adaptive_protection_config {
        layer_7_ddos_defense_config {
          enable = true
    }
  }
}
```

Open PR's Ref: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/10776

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring GCP Cloud Armor Adaptive Protection Plan as Advanced mode.

The rules or the policies of the Managed Protection Plan will only work if your project is enrolled under the "ManagedProtection Plan" and this is a Licenced Feature in GCP.

Addressing your question, you can declare all the rules in the policy as shown below URL [1] and the list of Threat Intelligent Rules can be seen in the URL [2]

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_security_policy
[2]
https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/threat-intelligence#configure-nti

Hope it helps you. ( If it doesn't help, refer my below answer )

Thanks